# Asterisk AMI - UpdateConfig not working

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

We are using Asterisk (8.1.11)/FreePBX (2.10.1.9). I am trying to modify voicemail.conf using AMI.

The line in voicemail.conf I'm trying to modify looks like:

```
2999 => 1234,Hotline,,someemail@company.com,attach=no|saycid=yes|envelope=yes|delete=no
```

I'm trying to modify the notification email address.
Using telnet to port 5038 I enter the following:

```
Action: login  
Username: username  
Secret: password

Action: UpdateConfig  
SrcFilename: voicemail.conf  
DstFilename: vmtest.conf  
Action-00000: Update  
Cat-00000: default  
Var-00000: 2999  
Value-00000: >1234,Hotline,,email@example.com,attach=no|saycid=yes|envelope=yes|delete=no  
ActionID: 123456789
```

This results in:

```
Response: Success  
ActionID: 123456789
```

This has the effect of creating the file "vmtest.conf", but the update does not occur. I've tried adding new categories, deleting variable, appending new variables - all report success, but nothing really changes.

I don't have much hair left to pull out at this point! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If that is your exact code, then you are missing a 0 for `action-`,`cat-`,`var-`,`value-`.

Should be:

```
Action: UpdateConfig
SrcFilename: voicemail.conf
DstFilename: vmtest.conf
Action-000000: Update
//          ^
Cat-000000: default
//       ^
Var-000000: 2999
//       ^
Value-000000: >1234,Hotline,,email@example.com,attach=no|saycid=yes|envelope=yes|delete=no
//         ^
ActionID: 123456789
```

I tried without the 6th 0 and I got success but it didn't change the file just like you are experiencing.

Comment: I've added comments to highlight where the OP needs to make changes. **I don't know for sure that leading `//` is actually comment syntax;** ***please change it if I'm wrong.***